# CMS for multiple domains in same language

Tags: content-management-system, multiple-domains

We have a site which is based in US (ex. www.example.com). We've been tasked to create  multiple sites for users of UK and Australia. Both of these will have different domains (ex. www.example.co.uk and www.example.co.au), These sites will share the same common pages backend. About 80% of the content is the same on all the versions but there will be a few sections  like contact, partners and product offerings which are different

**Example**

***US site*** (www.example.com) has 4 Pages:

- Home
- About
- Products
- Contact

***UK Site*** (www.example.co.uk) also has the same pages

- Home (The same as US with minor differences like the banner images. The URL will be www.example.co.uk)
- About (Different content, the URL should be www.example.co.uk/about)
- Products  (The same as US with minor content diffences in the offering, but URL should be www.example.co.uk/services)
- Contact (Different content, the URL should be www.example.co.uk/contact)

How do I go about setting up the UK and AU version of the site which use the same backend and most of the same content as the US site, but has a few page differences and different domain?

Can any one please recommend a few good CMS tools which will help achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

as far as I can tell, most CMSes will be able to provide you with some form of content-sharing.

It does depend on the amount of content you are having, if you have a relatively small set (e.g. the 4 pages in your answer), then you might be best served by just duplicating the pages. If you are looking at tens, hundreds or more documents, then you should look at a properly structured approach.

Can you give some hints as to the amount of documents?

Note: I work for [Hippo](http://onehippo.com)

Answer (score 0):

Go for Typo3!
Supports Multi domain and Multi lingual sites very effectively.
Once the development for a single domain is over you don't even need a developer for adding more domains. That is you don't need to code for multi domains, just need to learn a few things.