# Subsites in Orchard

Tags: content-management-system, orchardcms

I want to use the Orchard cms for developing my website. But the requirement is to have a site for each country under the same domain something like a subsite.

eg: mydomain.com/uk/home, mydomain.com/us/home, mydomain.com/au/home,etc

when the user logs in we have to check where the user comes from and redirect the user to the corresponsding website.

In Orchard we can create only 1 website and i am not sure how to add subsites like how we can do in Sharepoint.

My question is is similar to the one linked below exccept that I had decided to use Orchard CMS.
[CMS for multiple domains in same language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816180/cms-for-multiple-domains-in-same-language)

Please let me know if it is possible in Orchard.

Answer (score 1):

In order to create multiple sites with the same Orchard instance, you will have to enable the MultiTenancy module. Also, you can access the details per each site as shown here: [MultiTenancy Orchard - How to find out which tenant the request is coming from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15640465/multitenancy-orchard-how-to-find-out-which-tenant-the-request-is-coming-from)

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it , but this artlice :

http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Setting-up-a-multi-tenant-orchard-site

Gives details on setting up a multi tenant site.

Might Help.