# MultiTenancy Orchard - How to find out which tenant the request is coming from

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, multi-tenant

I have searched for quite a while, but I have not found any thread explaining how exactly to find out which Tenant is the current one in code. For example, I want to change some logic based off of what Tenant is active like so:

```
            IQueryable<ContentPartRecord> getContentPartDates;
            if (Tenat == ExampleTenant)
            {
                getContentPartDates = GetContentPartDates((int)Id)
                .Where(ss => ss.SalesStatus == "Guaranteed")
                .OrderBy(x => x.start_date);
            }else {
                getContentPartDates = GetContentPartDates((int) Id).OrderBy(x => x.start_date);
            }
```

What exactly is the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inject `ShellSettings` in ctor. This object contains all data (from *Settings.txt* file) about the shell (ie. tenant) in which current unit of work executes.

Comment: Hi, I know this thread is old but hopefully someone will pick this up. Is there anyway to get the current tenant settings within a static class method? Cheers

Comment: @RobWhite No way, sorry. If you really want to use static methods, either pass `ShellSettings` as an argument or pass `WorkContext`/`ILifetimeScope` as an argument and call `.Resolve<ShellSettings>()` on it.